# CLT theorem and Berry–Esseen bounds for this special case of sampling

Tags: central-limit-theorem, approximation

Consider a finite set $S=\{s_1,s_2,..s_n\}$, where $a \leq s_i\leq b$ are integers. Each element in $S$ can be chosen to a subset $S'$ in probability $p$.
We consider $n$ to be very large.

My question: How is there a way to messure how the mean element in $S'$ (i.e., $(s'_1+s'_2...+s'_{n'})/n'=s'$, where $n'$ is the number of elements in $S'$) to the mean element in $S$ (denoted by $s$)?

Formally, this means, given an error parameter $\alpha$, and mean values $s, s'$ I am trying to find the probability that
$Pr(|s-s'|< \alpha)$.

Since $n$ is large, I consider to use the  central limit theorem and use Berry–Esseen theorem to approximate the error, which depends on $n$. But I cannot express the problem as a sum of independent random variables, since this not a "standard way" of using sampling with replacement.

What can I do to approximate error?

Note: I did not found how to express the problem *cannot* as sum of independt RVs. For example, suppose we denote $X_i$ if element i is chosen or not- then

$$s'=(\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i *s_i )/(\sum_{i=0}^n X_i).$$

And this cannot be expressed a a sum of independent RVs, as done in CLT or Berry Essen Thorems.

Comment: What kinds of objects are the $s_i$ and how do you measure closeness?

Comment: Every object is an integer between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: the average=mean. i.e., sum of all elements divided by number of elements.

Comment: In what sense is the arithmetic mean a measure of "closeness"??

Comment: +1 Why can you not express $s^\prime$ as the sum of independent random variables?  After all, it is explicitly constructed in terms of such a sum!

Comment: @whuber - since the number of elements in S' is random.

Comment: For example: suppose X_i denotes if element i is chosen or not- then s'=(\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i *s_i )/(\sum_{i=0}^n X_i). This cannot be expressed a a sum of independent RVs.

Comment: Let me check my understanding of "chosen to a subset ... with probability $p.$" Their sum can be expressed in terms of $n$ *independent* random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ where $X_i=s_i$ with probability $p$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise. The sum of the chosen elements equals the sum of the $X_i.$

Comment: Yes, but you need to divide the sum by the number of elements in S', which is a random varible (and not constant).

Comment: @whuber This is why classic CLT and Berry-Esseen cannot be applied to this case

Comment: That is correct, and I think it gets to the heart of the matter.  But doesn't it take only a slight modification to handle the random denominator?  As $n$ grows large , $n^\prime$ approaches $pn$ sufficiently rapidly.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it will work for some cases. If $a$ and $b$ are equal, then there is still an error depends only on $n$. I think there should be a better bound in such case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to ensure whether I have understood the question correctly or not. $n$ is 'very large' and $S=\{s_1,\dots, s_n\}$.
Now with probability $p\in(0,1)$, each $s_i$ is chosen to form the collection $S'$ (where $X_i:=I_{s_i \in S'}$).
Then
$$s'=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i I(s_i \in S')}{\sum_{i=0}^n I(s_i \in S')}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i X_i}{n'}$$
and $s=\sum_{i=0}^n s_i/n$. (We have to keep in our mind that $n'$ and $s'$ are random and $p$ is fixed.)
Also let $m:=min\{|a|,|b|\} \le |s_i|\le max\{|a|,|b|\}=:M.$

Now, this might help you:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i I(s_i \in S')}{n'} - \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i}{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sum X_i} \left(\sum_{i=0}^n s_i X_i - \frac{n'}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n s_i\right) \\ 
&= \frac{n}{n'} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n s_i X_i - p \sum_{i=0}^n s_i\right) - \left(\frac{n'}{n}-p\right)\frac{\sum s_i}{\sum X_i}
\end{align}

- Now, for the first part, you need a weighted version of CLT - check [Lyapunov CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT) condition (or Lindeberg condition).
- Lyapunov CLT with variables $Y_i=s_i X_i$ will give you $$\frac{\sum s_iX_i - p \sum s_i}{p(1-p)\sqrt{\sum s_i^2}} \to N(0,1)$$ as $n\to \infty.$ (I have not checked thoroughly though, please check them - you might need boundedness of the random variables.)
- $m\sqrt{n}\le \sqrt{\sum s_i^2}\le M\sqrt{n}$ - for simplified calculations, you have to assume $m>0$ - though this assumption can be relaxed.
- For the other part, note $\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n'}{n}-p\right) \to N(0,1)$.
- $$\frac{\sum s_i}{\sum X_i} = \left(\frac{\sum s_i}{n}\right)\frac{n}{n'} \to \left(\frac{\sum s_i}{pn}\right)$$ Now $s_i$ are bounded which gives you required consistency from here.

For CLT type result, I would tweak the previous part in this way,
\begin{align}
&P\left(\sqrt{n}|\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i I(s_i \in S')}{n'} - \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n s_i}{n}|>\epsilon\right) \\
&\le P\left(\sqrt{n}|\frac{n}{n'} \cdot \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=0}^n s_i X_i - p \sum_{i=0}^n s_i\right)|>\epsilon/2\right) + P\left(\sqrt{n}|\left(\frac{n'}{n}-p\right)\frac{\sum s_i}{n'}|>\epsilon/2\right) \\ 
&= P\left(\frac{n}{n'} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|\left(\sum_{i=0}^n s_i X_i - p \sum_{i=0}^n s_i\right)|>\epsilon/2\right) + P\left(\frac{\sum s_i}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{n'} \cdot \sqrt{n}|\left(\frac{n'}{n}-p\right)|>\epsilon/2\right)
\end{align}

- You can use [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) with $\frac{n'}{n}\to p$ and the normality you got from the Lyapunov CLT here.
- For the second part, use boundedness of $\sum_1^n s_i/n$ and a Slutsky theorem type approach will give you some bound.

Sorry for the mess.

### Edit:

There should be another condition on the values of $s_i$'s. These values should be such that $\sum_{i=0}^n s_i/n \to c$ for some constant $c$ as $n \to \infty$